# Intel Intrinsics 256i struct access performance

Tags: c++, c, performance, struct, intrinsics

I am currently working with Intel Intrinsics, and have been unable to find any answer for this question:

If I (for instance) want to shuffle 64bit elements around in a __m256i register across lanes, I would use the Intrinsics function _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(), which has a throughput of 3 clock cycles.

Example:

```
__m256i initial_register = {1,2,3,4}; //test values
__m256i shuffled_register =  _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(initial_register, 0b01101100);
```

The *shufled_register* variable would now have the values {2, 3, 4, 1} instead.

However, is this more efficient than doing it this way:

```
__m256i initial_register = {1,2,3,4};
__m256i shuffled_register;

shuffled_register.m256i_i64[0] = initial_register.m256i_i64[1];
shuffled_register.m256i_i64[1] = initial_register.m256i_i64[2];
shuffled_register.m256i_i64[2] = initial_register.m256i_i64[3];
shuffled_register.m256i_i64[3] = initial_register.m256i_i64[0];
```

The end result seems to be the same and there are cases (e.g. if I only want to insert one 64bit into a register from another register), where this seems to be more clear and simple to write.

Comment: This may depend on your microarchitecture. On, say, Intel's Haswell, all AVX lane-crossing instructions have at least 3 cycles latency (not throughput). You wouldn't gain anything by using two (or more) separate instructions.

Comment: You should add the AVX2 tag to your question.  You don't need both the C and C++ tags.  You're using binary literals which only C++ supports but why not just use `_MM_SHUFFLE(2,3,4,1)`. It's more readable I think than `0b01101100` and works for C as well (even if GCC supports binary literals in C).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Will update tags. In this case, the reason for not using shuffle was that it cannot work across the 128bit lanes. Of course, there is the permute intrinsic then... My example was probably a bit bad actually. The real-life problem that made me think about this was that I had 2 registers, which I needed to shuffle inbetween, and that was why this seemed easier to read and write in code (than all the intrinsic functions).

Comment: I did not suggest to use another shuffle intrinsic. I suggested to use the `_MM_SHUFFLE(1,2,3,0)` macro which should be the same as `0b01101100`.  But that's just person preferere.